# Slick carousel functions not executing

Tags: jquery, slider

I am instantiating the Slick slider, but whatever functions I call on it are having no effect. From my code and in the console I am trying slickGoto, unslick etc and nothing happens. I also tried briefly upgrading to slick 1.5 and was still having the same issue.

In stepping through the code, it will call the function, but it seems not to do anything. Anything obviously an issue with the code I'm using to call it? I am completely at a loss where to look next

```
if (mysite.$carousel.length) {
    mysite.$carousel.slick({
        accessibility : true,
        autoplay : true,
        autoplaySpeed : 10000,
        pauseOnHover : false,
        fade : true,
        dots: true,
        appendArrows : $('.carousel-arrows-wrapper'),
        appendDots : $('.carousel-dots-wrapper')
    });
    $('.slick-pause').on('click', function(){
        var $pauseBtn = $(this);
        if ($pauseBtn.hasClass('paused')){
            mysite.$carousel.slickPlay();
            $pauseBtn.removeClass('paused');
        } else {
            mysite.$carousel.slickPause();
            $pauseBtn.addClass('paused');
        }
    });
}
```

It is changing the 'paused' attribute of the slider, but the slider is not actually pausing.. It continues to play.

And it looks like from investigating the carousel object, that it's not fully 'there'. If I examine [0].slick, it looks like none of the items are filled out properly, even though the slider is sliding properly.

[image: slick object]

The code will work on any mockup/prototype (and the slick object will have settings for $dots, $list, $nextArrow etc). But when integrated into a proprietary CMS it will fail.

This is maybe too localized, but I'm really looking at ways to try and figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `.slickPause()`, or `.slickPlay()`, call `.slick('slickPause')` or `.slick('slickPlay')`.

From the [slick documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/):

> Methods are called on slick instances through the slick method itself in version 1.4

Here's a fiddle you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/wd3eapez/1/

```
$('.slick-pause').on('click', function(){
    var $pauseBtn = $(this);
    if ($pauseBtn.hasClass('paused')){
        $(".slider").slick('slickPlay');
        $pauseBtn.removeClass('paused');
    } else {
        $(".slider").slick('slickPause');
        $pauseBtn.addClass('paused');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi.. I'm using version 1.3 in the code above. I was having the same trouble but only in certain circumstances with version 1.5 using the new function return method

Comment: Do you think you could create a fiddle that demonstrates the problem with version 1.5?

Comment: I'm having difficulty reproducing it. It's only happening when integrated with a CMS that has a bunch of additional stuff happening there. I just can't comprehend how that would change the slider object

Comment: Is it possible that the CMS you are using already includes an older version of the slick slider? I added v 1.3 to my fiddle, and it does break it without producing an error in the console: http://jsfiddle.net/wd3eapez/2/